PS - Import CSV with quotes
I have a few files which I should import into a database. The files are 30-40MB.
CSV files' delimiter is tabulator.
For example:



Header1
Header2
Header3




1
rand name
5674


2
his name
663452


3
"her name
1423254


4
other name
876


5
I have no idea
234


6
"""why use it
2342



I tried this:
$Import_file = Import-Csv "$($FileSource)" -Encoding Default -Delimiter "`t" -Header "Header1","Header2","Header3"

#Connection and table definition part

try {
    $Import_file | ForEach-Object {
        $row = $Import_Table.NewRow()
        $row.FIELD1 = [string]($_.Header1)
        $row.FIELD2 = [string]($_.Header2)
        $row.FIELD3 = [string]($_.Header3)
        $Import_Table.Rows.Add($row)
    }
}

The problem is the quotes. It works as text qualifier.
The 3rd row's 2nd field's content will be: "her name    1423254 4   other name  876 5   I have no idea  234"
It won't keep the quotes. How can I escape and keep qoutes? Is it possible that there won't give up the performance?
The environmnet is Powershell 5.1 .
Didn't find any kind of parameter to manage this.
Try to split the rows, but I'm afraid of to lose the performance.
Solution
iRon solved this.
Get-Content $FileSource | ForEach-Object { $_.Split([Char]9) }
This can manage the quotes.

csv standard foresees fields values are always within double quotes. It allows to deal with quotes in the field itself if needed to be. If your file is not consistent all along for this you will get in trouble. As a workaround you may investigate replace tabulation by "tabulation" and fin a way to deal with start and end of line. Real fix would be to have proper csv.

Splitting each row with Get-Content $FileSource | ForEach-Object { $_.Split([Char]9) } shouldn't have any impact on the performance.

@iRon Many thanks! It works. Get-Content solved this problem.

Specify a program that tests the CSV file for validity. If the CSV does not pass the test, then it is not ready to be imported. Between different organizations or groups, this would be part of the SLA.

If possible, you should try to change how the CSV is made.
Meanwhile, a patch though I bet there are infinitely more efficent ways to deal with it:
$Import_File = Get-Content -Path .\res.csv | 
    ForEach-Object Replace '"' , '\"' |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $temp = [pscustomobject]::new()
        foreach ($Header in $_.psobject.properties.name) {
            Add-Member -InputObject $temp -MemberType NoteProperty `
                -Name $Header -Value ($_.$Header -replace '\\"', '"')
        } 
        $temp
    }


We can't change the source file's format. Technically we can, but the developers have more important tasks. We can't do it in a few month.
